# Difficulty in writing LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq, filesystems

I have written a query to fetch count of lines matching the criteria.

The linq query that i have used is:

```
int result = File.ReadLines(filePath).Count(line => line.StartsWith(word));
```

Here, i require the lines matching the criteria not the count. Please help

Comment: Replace `Count` with `Where` and it will return an IEnumerable of strings which represent each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<string> linesMatching = File.ReadLines(filePath)
    .Where(line => line.StartsWith(word));
```

On this way you have the lines and - if you create a collection from it - also the count:

```
List<string> lines = linesMatching.ToList();
int count = lines.Count;
```

Note that you cannot reuse the query once it is executed since you're using `File.ReadLines` which uses a `StreamReader` under the hood. Once it was used it is disposed. So this will raise an exception since the query was already executed at `ToList`:

```
int count = linesMatching.Count();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
File.ReadLines(filePath).Where(line => line.StartsWith(word));
```

Just change it to a `Where` instead.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx

> Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx):

```
List<string> lines = File.ReadLines(filePath)
                         .Where(line => line.StartsWith(word)).ToList();
```

You can then do:

```
int count = lines.Count;
```

To get the number of lines matching the predicate

Answer (score 1):

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(filePath).Where(line => line.StartsWith(word));
var total = lines.Count;
```

Comment: This won't compile because lines is not a list ;-)